# Simple Makefile for multi-files

Tags: makefile, linux-device-driver

all:

I have 2 files, module1.c and module2.c which contains functions needed by the third file, big_module.c. My Makefile complained of not finding functions defined in module1.c and module2.c. These functions are needed by big_module.c Could you please help me defining my Makefile so it would work?

## module1.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

int module1 (struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{ return 0; }

int __init init_module1 (void)
{ return 0; }

void __exit cleanup_module1 (void)
{ }
```

## module2.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/io.h>

unsigned long virt_addr;

int module2(struct file * filp, struct vm_area_struct * vma)
{ return 0; }

int __init init_module2 (void)
{ return 0; }

void __exit cleanup_module2 (void) { }
```

## big_module.c

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/vt_kern.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Example");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Your Name Here");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    init_module1();
    init_module2();
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
    cleanup_module1();
    cleanup_module2();
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

## Makefile:

```
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

obj-m += big_module.o
obj-m += module1.o
obj-m += module2.o

modules:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

## Errors:

```
>     uu@uu-VirtualBox:~/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK$ sudo make
>     make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0uu/build M=/home/uu/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK modules
>     make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-3.10'
>       CC [M]  /home/uu/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK/big_module.o
>     /home/uu/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK/big_module.c: In function ‘hello_init’:
>     /home/uu/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK/big_module.c:14:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_module1’
> [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>     /home/uu/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK/big_module.c:15:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_module2’
> [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>     /home/uu/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK/big_module.c: In function ‘hello_cleanup’:
>     /home/uu/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK/big_module.c:21:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘cleanup_module1’
> [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>     /home/uu/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK/big_module.c:22:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘cleanup_module2’
> [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>     cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
>     make[2]: *** [/home/uu/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK/big_module.o] Error 1
>     make[1]: *** [_module_/home/uu/UCSC-Ext/LDDII/Assignment3/ASK] Error 2
>     make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-3.10'
>     make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: We cannot see all those header files, we don't know what's in them or how they're supposed to work. The compiler is telling you that when `big_module.c` calls `init_module1()`, it has no idea what you're talking about, so clearly there's something wrong with your use of headers. But most important, this is much too complicated; you should always start with something small and simple and work your way up.

Comment: Also you should never run `make` as root (with `sudo`).  In some situations you may want to run `make install` as root, but not make.  One misplaced space in the makefile or variable and oops, there goes your entire system.

Comment: I removed all the of headers file in both module1.c and module2.c, and has only 1 header inclusion (#include <linux/module.h>) in big_module.c file, but the same problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

all:

I found the solution to my question. It's in the Makefile which should look
like the following:

Makefile

=======================

KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

obj-m := big_module.o

big_module-objs :=      module1.o module2.o

modules:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

=======================